# Trapping a sphere in a trefoil knot

Tags: knot-theory

Is it possible to trap a sphere in the center of a trefoil knot? It seems like with three points of contact it should be possible. Admittedly not big into math, but a craftsman who loves trapping marbles. Sincerely appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: It takes four points to trap a sphere.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180440/trapping-a-sphere-in-a-trefoil-knot, without notice to either site.

Comment: Thank you Tony. Maybe if I give the inside lines a heavy curve to touch more surface area it could work... And yes, Gerry, I posted it to overflow first, and it was mentioned this might be a better resource for me.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where you want to trap the sphere.  Usually, a trefoil goes around the outside (major radius) of the torus twice and smaller (minor) three times. We sometimes call this a (3,2) torus knot. The best place to put a marble or sphere would be the center of the torus, but this only will have three points of contact, and as TonyK stated, we need 4 if we want to hold the sphere.

But, if we use the trefoil where we switch the meridian and longitude, we get three "strands" which flow around the torus, a (2,3) torus knot.  See some useful pictures [here.](http://www.rwgrayprojects.com/Lynn/DoubleTorus/dt01.html) Then a few marbles could roll around inside the area where the torus would be, and I believe, be trapped.

If you want to let the trefoil be in some other configuration where it doesn't necessarily lie in a torus, I am sure you can get it to hold a sphere stationary.  Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example suggested by
Scott Carnahan
in response to a different question, "[Hanging a ball with string](https://mathoverflow.net/q/43791/6094),"
which I include in case it might yield some intuition.

---

[image: ScottCarnahan]